# Issues with multiple y axis ranges in plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I am attempting to plot multiple lines on the same graph in plotly. The problem is for every variable that is being plotted, plotly is creating new set of y axis values. Can this be solved. I want the same y axis for all the line plots that I create. Following is the code and the plot generated.

```
p1 <- plot_ly(data = st_data, x = ~Date) %>% add_lines(y = ~Close,name = 
"Close") %>%
add_lines(y=~Bollinger,name="Bollinger")
```

[image]
In the graph the y axis has values ranging once from 61.85 to 65.90 and again from 62.15 to 65.49.

Ideally I am looking for the y axis values to be between 61.85 and 65.90 and the two lines plotted on the same axis.

```
Adding the input data:
Date            Close   Bollinger
1/30/2015 9:34  65.55   NA
1/30/2015 9:34  65.43   NA
1/30/2015 9:35  65.52   NA
1/30/2015 9:35  65.37   NA
1/30/2015 9:36  65.68   65.184
1/30/2015 9:36  65.4    65.303
1/30/2015 9:36  65.51   65.4155
1/30/2015 9:36  65.8    65.499
1/30/2015 9:36  65.6    65.548
```

Comment: Can you add some of your input data?

Comment: Please provide data for an example.
But it might be because your variables are factors. Just cast them as numerical vectors and it should work.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Thanks for suggesting what was needed to complete the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code should already work. I think [sjakw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4690574/sjakw) is correct in that you have some other code that creates a problem. Try opening a new script, and paste the following code. You should get a plot with a single y axis.

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
st_data <- fread('Date , Close,  Bollinger
                 1/30/2015 9:34,  65.55,   NA 
                 1/30/2015 9:34,  65.43,   NA 
                 1/30/2015 9:35,  65.52,   NA 
                 1/30/2015 9:35,  65.37,   NA 
                 1/30/2015 9:36,  65.68,   65.184 
                 1/30/2015 9:36,  65.4 ,   65.303 
                 1/30/2015 9:36,  65.51,   65.4155 
                 1/30/2015 9:36,  65.8 ,   65.499 
                 1/30/2015 9:36,  65.6 ,   65.548 ')
p1 <- plot_ly(data = st_data, x = ~Date) %>% add_lines(y = ~Close,name = "Close") %>%
  add_lines(y=~Bollinger,name="Bollinger")
p1
```

I like the following approach better.

```
p2 <- plot_ly()
p2 <- add_lines(p, data = st_data, x = ~Date, y = ~Close, name = "Close")
p2 <- add_lines(p, data = st_data, x = ~Date, y = ~Bollinger, name = "Bollinger")
p2
```

Your data is in "wide" format. You can use similar code to the [R Plotly Book](https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/scatter-traces.html#line-plots) if you melt your data into "long" format:

```
st_data_long <- melt.data.table(st_data, id = "Date", measure.vars = c("Close", "Bollinger"), 
                                value.factor = TRUE, variable.name = "PriceType", value.name = "Price")
p3 <- plot_ly(st_data_long, x = ~Date, y = ~Price) %>%
  add_lines(color = ~PriceType)
p3
```

I also tried it with a sample dataset included in R:

```
# First make Date one column
airquality <- data.table(airquality)
airquality[, Date := do.call(paste, .SD), .SDcols = c("Month", "Day")]

p4 <- plot_ly()
p4 <- add_lines(p1, data = airquality, x = ~Date, y = ~Ozone, name = "Ozone")
p4 <- add_lines(p1, data = airquality, x = ~Date, y = ~Temp, name = "Temp")
p4
```